# How to autocomplete Vue templates in Visual Studio Code

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I am starting to learn Vue, using Visual Studio Code. I downloaded an extension that adds Vue code snippets (Vue 2 Snippets by hallowtree).

When I start to type `"v"` in a Vue template, suggestions are shown (`v-on`, `v-bind`, etc.),
but afterward, no suggestions or autocompletions are shown.

In the following example template, `v-on` is suggested, but afterward, no suggestions for `"click"` or any other event. Also, nothing is suggested after `"@"`:

```html
<button v-on:click="changeLink">Click to change Link</button>
<button @click="changeLink">Click to change Link</button>
```

And in this example, `v-bind` is suggested, but afterward, no suggestions for `"href"` or any other HTML properties/attributes:

```html
<a v-bind:href="link">Link</a> 
<a :href="link">Link</a>
```

Although it's good for me for practicing, it will become a liability. 
Are there any extensions, options, or commands I can set up to improve the developer experience?

Answer (score 15):

Vetur has had [experimental template interpolation](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/CHANGELOG.html#template-interpolation-completion) for autocomplete and "diagnostics / hover / definition / references" within HTML templates since February 2019.

Enable the `Vetur › Experimental: Template Interpolation Service` option in your VS Code settings to turn on this feature.

Answer (score 4):

add the [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur) extension on `visual-studio-code` it includes many other nice features besides auto completion vue code

Comment: didnt work for me 
I have Vue 2 Snippets by hallowtree and disable it for vetur but nothing happend no suggestions even for vue

Comment: @eomer im currently using it and it works fine maybe something is wrong on your settings

Comment: Doesn't work for me as well. Even `import` is not recognized. Weird.
Uninstalling VSCode and installing it again did the trick.

Comment: All Vue extensions dont work for me (Vue2+Vuetify).